# How to pass a comparator to the inner map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I need to implement two nested maps with a customised comparator for the inner map.

I have:

```
struct Rank {
    Rank() = default;
    int rank = 0;
    bool condition = false;
};
```

and the comparator

```
struct compareRank {
    bool operator()(const Rank& lhs, const Rank& rhs) const {
        return lhs.rank < rhs.rank;
    }
};
```

In my `main()` function I declare:

```
map<int, map<string, Rank, compareRank>> db;
```

The idea behind this is the following: the inner `map` should sort its strings by their rank.

However, when I try to do this:

```
db[3]["hello"] = Rank();
```

the compile says:

> no matching function for call to object of type 'const compareRank'

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `std::map` compares keys, not values

Comment: @sp2danny: Wrong box mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` is a key based container.  That means it sorts the keys, not the values.  `compareRank` takes a `Rank` while the map is trying to sort the `std::string` key.

If you don't need the `std::string` key then you could consider a `std::set<Rank>`.

If you need to have both `std::string` and `Rank` act as keys you might be able to use a [`boost::bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)